# How can we apply class from html to angularjs template

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have my templte in angularjs :

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }"></li>
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)">
            Previous
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == \'...\' }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)">
            {{ pageNumber }}
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)">
            Next
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }"></li>
</ul>
```

My Template in my html

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span
            aria-hidden="true">&laquo; Prev</span><span
            class="sr-only">Previous</span></a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next"><span
            aria-hidden="true">Next &raquo;</span><span
            class="sr-only">Next</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

How can i use class from my template in html to angularjs template like my template in first script??

Comment: Did you try to simply add your class into angular's temple by adding class = ... ?
<li class="abc" ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }"></li>

Comment: @vicnoob it's not working when i add class="" to angularjs

Comment: Im not using angular, but you can try ng-class="{{ disabled : pagination.current == 1, page-item: true }.
But it's weird that you can not add class directly on it. Have you included css file?

Comment: @vicnoob that's working thank you very much